# Afferent and Efferent coupling metrics for groovy code in SonarQube 5.1.2

Tags: groovy, sonarqube, metrics, sonar-runner, sonarqube5.1

I am using SonarQube v5.1.2 with Groovy plugin 1.0.1. I have been trying to find a way to have the Afferent and Efferent coupling metrics displayed for our Groovy and Grails based project, but in vain.

From the official documentation of Groovy plugin for SonarQube the below is quoted:

> It leverages CodeNarc to raise issues against coding rules, Gmetrics for cyclomatic complexity and Cobertura or JaCoCo for code coverage.

[Source: Groovy SonarQube Plugin](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Groovy+Plugin)

But in the official website for GMetrics, its mentioned that Afferent and Efferent coupling can be computed:

[GMetrics Afferent Coupling Metrics](http://gmetrics.sourceforge.net/gmetrics-AfferentCouplingMetric.html)
and
[GMetrics Efferent Coupling Metrics](http://gmetrics.sourceforge.net/gmetrics-EfferentCouplingMetric.html)

However, I dont find it anywhere in SonarQube. Is there anyway by which it can be displayed in v5.1.2?

I found the below link in which it has been described how to display it in SonarQube 3.7, but its not available anymore in 5.1.2.
[Afferent and Efferent coupling in SonarQube 3.7](http://sonarqube-archive.15.x6.nabble.com/How-to-see-afferent-and-efferent-couplings-in-Sonar-3-7-td5016520.html)

Am I missing out on something in here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sonar groovy plugin (last released version is `1.2`) only computes files-related metrics. Package measures are not handled. Consequently, `Afferent Coupling` and `Efferent Coupling` metrics are currently ignored, although we are indeed using `GMetrics`.

For the time being, you then unfortunately won't be able to display these metrics for your projects.

I created the following ticket in order to integrate these values: [SONARGROOV-43](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGROOV-43)

Comment: Thanks a lot Michael for your response. I hope it gets handled soon. Accepting your answer.

BTW, are you a part of the team which handles the groovy plugin?

Comment: I'm part of the team, yes!